# Servo motor power boost

Tags: amplifier, motor, servo

I was pondering this problem:

Given a standard small hobby servo motor, is it feasible to reuse it's internal components to drive a larger DC motor?

I tried disconnecting the motor and reconnecting a larger motor and, as expected, the motor turned but slowly and with little torque.

I'm hoping someone might have done this already and have advice.

-Tom

Comment: Bad question, anything is possible. This question might be closed because its purely opinionated. Please ask a specific question, edit your question. Thanks (It also might help to elaborate on what you've found so far, and include a picture or a diagram)

Comment: Driver resistance needs to be much smaller than DC motor winding resistance (DCR) which controls torque and start/stop current. So bypass drivers or switching transistors must be scaled according to the motor DCR in addition to meeting voltage rating. Op Amps are very low current compared to motors.

Comment: Laptop: I've made changes.

Comment: Tony: thanks for Op Amp info, guess I'll have to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit inside a hobby servo is optimized to provide best performance for the size, so all the components are matched to work together. The motor driver output (inside the control IC or external transistors) is sized to suit the installed motor.

You could replace the transistors with more powerful ones *if* the IC is able to drive them (perhaps possible with FETs, but probably not bipolar transistors because they would need more current than the IC can provide). To find out if it is possible you should examine the datasheet of the control IC used in your servo. Alternatively you could try tacking a booster amp onto the existing motor output, but this may not work because the controller expects to see a motor there.

Assuming you can make a more powerful motor driver, the next problem is tuning the servo for fastest response without overshoot. The [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) (Proportional Integral Differential) algorithm built into the control IC is tuned to the particular mechanism it was designed for. When you put a larger motor in its response will probably be different, so chances are the servo will work poorly.

Analog control ICs are usually tuned with passive components (resistors, capacitors) so there's a chance you might be able to tune an analog servo to use a larger motor by changing their values. Digital servos are controlled by firmware inside the controller which cannot be changed, so you are stuck with whatever tuning they have.

In short, while you *could* modify a hobby servo to use a larger motor, it would be much easier to just buy a larger servo to start with. If you want to take the control board out of a hobby servo and use it to control your own mechanism then get an analog servo with equivalent sized motor, and be prepared for a lot of fiddling to get it working properly.

Comment: Great answer, though I would add, small motor controllers usually ignore some motor characteristics that become more problematic as the motor becomes larger.

Comment: I suspect most hobby servo controllers ignore _all_ the motor characteristics, and are just tuned to the complete mechanism. Servo controller IC datasheets than I have examined make no reference to motor characteristics (Kt, Rm, Io, inductance, rotor inertia etc.).

Comment: Buying larger servos was my first thought but those puppies are several hundred pounds each, while you can pick up a good dc motor for under £30.